# How can i get a variable to change number depending on what the user has eneterd

Tags: javascript, html

So i am creating a simple dice game which you enter the guess of the dice roll and amount you wish to bet. I cant seem to figure out how i can get my balance to change when a user enters a number.

My code:

```js
//declaring global variables
var diceroll = 0;

var balance = 1000;

var stake = 0;
var guess = 0;

while (balance <= 0) {
  var guess = document.getElementById("guess").nodeValue;
  var stake = document.getElementById("stake").nodeValue;

  var diceroll = roll();

  if (guess === diceroll) {
    balance = balance + (stake * 5);
  } else {
    balance = balance - stake;
  }
}

//Rolling the dice
function roll() {
  "use strict";
  diceroll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
  alert(diceroll);
}




//Display balance
document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = balance;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
  <title>Dice-Game: GL HF</title>


</head>


<body>
  <p id="balance"></p>
  <form action="#">
    Enter guess:
    <input type="text" id="guess">
    <br>Enter stake:
    <input type="number" id="stake" name="stake">
    <br>
    <input type="button" name="play" onclick="roll()" value="PLAY!">
    <br>
  </form>


  <script src="Dice.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe it's just too early in the morning... but how is your while loop being called after page load?  I'm not seeing how it's linked to your roll function.  Don't you want to adjust the balance on roll()?

Comment: @Mike yeah, i want the balance to update when the dice has been rolled. I still have the issue of the balance staying at 1000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

1. The way I looked at it, your while loop wasn't doing anything.  The whole balance calculation wasn't even part of your roll function.  I removed it altogether.
2. You were using `.nodeValue` to get your guess and stake `input` values, which is deprecated.  It should just be `.value`.  Those two variables were returning `null`.
3. Your balance update wasn't being called with your function either, so it wouldn't have updated on the page even if the balance was actually updating.
4. Your declaration of global variables was a bit redundant and unnecessary.

   ```
   //declaring global variables
   var balance = 1000;

   //Rolling the dice
   function roll() {
       var guess = document.getElementById("guess").value;
       var stake = document.getElementById("stake").value;

       "use strict";
       var diceroll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);
       alert(diceroll);

       if(guess == diceroll) {
           balance = balance + (stake * 5);
       } else {
           balance = balance - stake;
       }

       //Update display balance
       document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = balance;
   }

   //Initial display balance
   document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = balance;
   ```

Comment: works a treat, thanks for the explanation as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
//Display balance
document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = balance;
```

inside of the loop.

I also don't think your while condition is correct..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
balance = parseInt(balance) - parseInt(stake);
```